# smallmatrix gives two different sizes

Tags: matrices

I have the following code inside a paragraph and it just looks odd to me because the two matrices have different sizes. Not only horizontally (as I'd expect) but vetrically. It just looks kind of weird and I'd like to know if there's anyway to get them to be the same size?

```
\left\{\left(\begin{smallmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{smallmatrix}\right), \left(\begin{smallmatrix}-1&\hfill 0\\ \hfill 0&-1\end{smallmatrix}\right)\right\}
```

[image: This is what it looks like]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Very nice problem! The key is in knowing that the minus sign has, by Knuth's decree, the same vertical dimensions as the plus sign.

In particular, the minus sign has a depth that gets in the way in the second small matrix.

You have two possibilities: either you “mormalize” the small matrix without signs, or you smash the minus sign.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

$\left\{\left(\begin{smallmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{smallmatrix}\right),
 \left(\begin{smallmatrix}-1&\hfill 0\\ \hfill 0&-1\end{smallmatrix}\right)\right\}$

\bigskip

$\left\{\left(\begin{smallmatrix}\vphantom{-}1&0\\0&1\end{smallmatrix}\right),
 \left(\begin{smallmatrix}-1&\hfill 0\\ \hfill 0&-1\end{smallmatrix}\right)\right\}$

\bigskip

$\left\{\left(\begin{smallmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{smallmatrix}\right),
 \left(\begin{smallmatrix}\smash[b]{-1}&\hfill 0\\ \hfill 0&-1\end{smallmatrix}\right)\right\}$

\end{document}
```

Note that just the space between the two rows is affected, so it's not necessary to smash the minus sign in the bottom row or to add `\vphantom{-}` in the bottom row.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help! So your first one is the one I gave you, the second one is making the first matrix smaller by putting an invisible minus sign in the first row and the third is making the second matrix smaller by smashing the minus sign, correct? What exactly does smash do because the minus sign looks the same size in all three.

Comment: @user46348 Yes, that's the order. With `\smash[b]{-}` we're telling TeX to disregard the fact that the symbol's bounding box extends below the base line. The glyph itself is not touched in any way, just the imaginary bounding box.